# How to create a list from results from a given list within a for loop?

Tags: python

I am doing googles python class. And came across this problem:

```
# A. match_ends
# Given a list of strings, return the count of the number of
# strings where the string length is 2 or more and the first
# and last chars of the string are the same.
# Note: python does not have a ++ operator, but += works.
```

I tried different approaches, but cant seem to get it to work. This is what i got now:

```
def match_ends(words):
words=sorted(words, key=len)
for i in words:
    if len(i)<2:
        print(i)
        words=words[1:]
        print(words)
        for i in words:
            if i[0:2]==i[-2:]:
                x=[]
                x.append[i]
```

How is this done?

Comment: Sample input? Sample output?

Comment: Do you have the original link to that question?

Comment: Also string or words?

Comment: Your indentation is off, please [edit] and fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
def match_ends(words):
    count = 0

    for word in words:
        if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Answer (score 5):

Easy to accomplish using `sum` and a generator expression:

```
def match_ends(words):
    return sum(len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1] for word in words)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic solution might be

```
def func(s):
  return len(s) >= 2 and s[0] == s[-1]

str_list = ['applea', 'b', 'cardc']

filtered_list = [s for s in str_list if (len(s) >= 2 and s[0] == s[-1])]
# or 
filtered_list = list(filter(func, str_list))

count = len(filtered_list)
```

Comment: There is no need to instantiate the list. Easier would be to do `sum(map(func, str_list))`

Answer (score 0):

pretty much the same as previous answers, but lambda

`match_ends = lambda ws: sum(1 for w in ws if len(w)>1 and w[0] == w[-1])`

or 'expanded' form

`match_ends = lambda words: sum(1 for word in words if len(word)>1 and word[0] == word[-1])`